# Error message re: MICE procedure in R to impute missing data

Tags: r, missing-data, r-mice

I am trying to use the mice procedure in R to impute missing data.
My database is 800k rows

I get this message when I enter this code:

Call the mice package:

```
library(mice)
```

> Warning message:
>   package ‘mice’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
>   Imputing the missing data.  The mice function takes care of the imputing process

```
imputedata <- mice(origdata,m=5,maxit=50,meth='pmm',seed=500)
```

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 822.4 Mb

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for how to run the procedure and not use up all the memory.  Thanks.

Comment: How many rows contain missing data? Also do you really need 50 iteration, default is `maxit = 5`. The error youre getting is not enough memory to run. A smaller data frame and less iterations may solve this

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try that.